# 2d Nav Goal RViz button not working with PR2

Tags: ros

I have been unsuccessfully trying to move our PR2 robot using the "2d Nav Goal" button in RViz.

This are the steps I do:

1. I start the map server up in the robot: `rosrun map_server map_server mymap.yaml`
2. I start the navigation stack up in the robot: `roslaunch pr2_2dnav pr2_2dnav.launch`
3. I start RViz in a laptop through: `roslaunch pr2_navigation_slam rviz_move_base_slam.launch`
4. I configure RViz by adding the Map visualization and `/map` topic. I set also the `map` frame as the fixed frame.

After that I can actually see the map and the PR2 model correctly positioned, but when I want to move the robot through the **2d Nav Goal** button, nothing happens.

In the terminal of the step 2, the followin Error is shown:

```
[c2-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_navigation_self_filter/self_filter]: can't locate node [self_filter] in package [pr2_navigation_self_filter]
[c2-0]: process[base_shadow_filter-6]: started with pid [20551]
[c2-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_navigation_self_filter/self_filter]: can't locate node [self_filter] in package [pr2_navigation_self_filter]
[c2-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [semantic_point_annotator/sac_inc_ground_removal_node]: can't locate node [sac_inc_ground_removal_node] in package [semantic_point_annotator]
```

I installed the package `ros-hydro-pr2-navigation-self-filter` in the robot and started all over again. The error appeared again.

As RViz runs in the laptop (NOTE: I tested the configuration variables and they were OK since I can make `rostopic echo` and `rostopic pub` correctly), I wanted to simulate the action of the button by publishing into the `/move_base_simple/goal` directly from c1 and nothing happened.

I read several answers in similar posts but none of them worked for me.

Am I missing something? Can I try something else to reveal the error source?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

you may try to install the same package in both machines to work, i encountred this error once and that was my solution...
Also, Can you specify which one is c1 and c2 (laptop or robot) to better help you ?

Good luck !